# Apache blocking multiple requests?

Tags: jquery, linux, apache, firewall, iptables

I have a web application that makes extensive use of jQuery. The system loads a base page and then dynamically loads other portions of the page using jQuery.

This has been working wonderfully for months. Now, all of a sudden, the base page loads just fine but clicking on buttons / links that dynamically load additional information fail. I've used apache-top to watch if the requests are even being sent to Apache, but they don't show up in the log at all.

I can only guess that the requests are being blocked on some low level, but I can't figure out why. I've disabled iptables, but that wasn't the issue.

It definitely appears to be that once a certain number of requests is reached, the additional requests are blocked. Or perhaps once a certain amount of bandwidth is reached, all additional requests are blocked. I have not configured any such blocking, however.

I have applied all patches and updates as they become available (via "yum update"), so I'm assuming something changed in one of the updates and I don't know what it is.

Any ideas on where to start looking to find the culprit?

(And just to be clear, standard HTML pages uploaded to the server load just fine and super fast -- it's only the dynamic portions of the page that are being blocked from loading.)

ADDED: In case it matters, I'm hosting the site on an AWS server (Amazon Cloud). WHM/cPanel is installed.

Comment: Could it be a cross-domain issue? What does the browser console say?

Comment: It's not a cross-domain issue. The requests are from the domain to the same domain. The browser console shows nothing. No timeouts, no errors, nothing. Oh, and sometimes the requests work and sometimes they don't. If it was cross-domain it would fail every time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. One of the dynamically loaded assets (that gets called a number of times per page) was very, very slow to respond, which was locking up all of the threads the browser was using so no additional assets could be loaded.

Once I replaced that asset everything started working again.